# querySelector error: Not valid selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am finding the max number of an element based on data attributes, however I want to convert jquery code to native vanilla js. I have tried to replace $ selector with querySelector of vanillaJS, but it throws an error like this. Is there a way I can convert this to vanilla JS. This is the error it returns.

```
DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': 'li:not(".expired")[data-arrange]' is not a valid selector
```

This is my code.

```
var max = Math.max.apply([], document.querySelector('li:not(".expired")[data-arrange]').map(function() {
            return $(this).data('arrange');
        }).get());
```

sample HTML

```
<ul>
  <li data-arrange="1" class="rec expired">bONIE</li>
  <li data-arrange-"4" class="rec">eDS</li>
  <li data-arrange="5" class="expired">bue</li>
  <li data-arrange="6" class="rec">mag</li>
</ul>
```

Thank you.

Comment: You don't need to use double quotes in the `.not` selector. The correct selector is `document.querySelector('li:not(.expired)[data-arrange]')`

Comment: Wait, did this selector work in jQuery?

Comment: @dloeda it probably ought to be `querySelectorAll` too

Comment: @AndrewBone I think so... But this returns a NodeList so `.map` will break

Comment: Can you provide the *original* jquery that you're trying to convert?  The code provided is not valid (so appears to be work-in-progress, which is fine).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple issues this code:

1. You cannot use `"` inside `.not` the selector
2. As @AndrewBone said, probably you want to use `querySelectorAll`
3. `querySelectorAll` returns a `NodeList[]` so `.map` will break the execution.

So I guess the correct code must be:

```js
var selector = 'li:not(.expired)[data-arrange]';
    var array = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(selector));
    var max = Math.max.apply(null, array.map(function(item) {
                return parseInt(item.dataset.arrange);
            }));

    console.info(max)
```

```html
<ul>
  <li data-arrange="1">1</li>
  <li data-arrange="4">4</li>
  <li data-arrange="5">5</li>
  <li data-arrange="6">6</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Still editing?  needs you to review the "correct" code.

Comment: querySelectorAll ?

Comment: thank you dloeda, however I am getting an unexpected token of ) after get I've tried to remove it and it returns an error Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: array.map(...).get is not a function because this is inside a function call and im using axios.

Comment: I've applied it but it doesnt return the max value. this is the original jquery code that is working.....       var max = Math.max.apply([], $('li:not(.expired)[data-arrange]').map(function() {
            return $(this).data('arrange');
        }).get());

Comment: Okay, I cannot find out the `get`. So NOW must be fixed

Comment: No problem @JohnWick =)

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it using dloeda's code. I've just modified it a liitle bit, because it returns an error using .get();

```
var selector = 'li:not(.expired)[data-arrange]';
var array = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(selector));
var max = Math.max.apply(Math, array.map(function(item) {
        return item.dataset.arrange;
 }));
```